# Subscribe emits Forbidden error

Tags: python, apache-spark, spark-streaming, pubnub

I have a two part python standalone application: a publisher and a subscriber.

The publisher generates fake JSON devices objects and published them on a channel called "devices." And as you would guess, the subscriber subscribes to the channel "devices."

(Additionally, given optional command line arguments, the publisher or subscriber can write JSON objects to a socket or a local directory where an Apache Spark Streaming context pickups the JSON objects and processes it. For now, this is not in the picture, as it's optional.)

However, my problem is when my subscriber runs, after the publisher has finished, I get "ERROR: Forbidden".

Here are the respective python code snippets for the publisher:

```
pubnub = Pubnub(publish_key="my_key", subscribe_key="my_key")
....
pubnub.publish(ch, device_msg)
```

In the subscriber python file I have the following init code:

```
def receive(message, channel):
  json.dumps(message)

def on_error(message):
   print ("ERROR: " + str(message))
....
pubnub = Pubnub(publish_key="my_keys", subscribe_key="my_keys")

# subscribe to a channel and invoke the appropriate callback when a message arrives on that 
# channel
#
pubnub.subscribe(channels=ch, callback=receive, error=on_error)
pubnub.start()
```

While the publisher, when run, seems to publish the JSON messages, all 120 in a loop, whereas the subscriber, when run, seems to fail with the following error message:

```
ERROR: Forbidden
```

My attempts to use "demo" keys have made no difference. Note that I'm using a trial account for PubNub.

Since this is one of my first app using its API, has anyone seen this problem before. Surely, something very obvious or trivial is amiss here.

Comment: Do you have Access Manager enabled on your keys in your PubNub acocunt? If so, read the note on that add-on: *NOTE: Once you enable Access Manager, you will need to grant permissions before sending data.* Let me know if that was the issue.

Comment: Hello Craig, Fearful of AM, I disabled it and used only the "demo" keys for sub/pub, yet I get Forbidden errors. I enabled AM, after which I granted me (dmatrix@comcast.net) for my app DevicesApp for the "free" keys. The "Add" failed with "There was a problem adding this user."

Comment: I am not following what you are saying here. demo keys do not have Access Manager and you shouldn't use them beyond a getting started test run anyways. On your keys, just disable Access Manager and work with that. Any further issues, send sub-key, errors, logs, code to support@pubnub.com and we'll handle there and post answer back here.

Comment: Craig, my apologies for any ambiguity. I have disabled the Access Manager (AM). The problem was user error: the perils of cut-and-pass sub/keys. I do have another issue that I'll mail to support@pubnub.com, along with with code snippet. (The app has many components ... (https://github.com/dmatrix/examples/tree/master/pubnub/py)

Comment: Thanks for reporting back and clarifying. Happens to the best of us. Cheers, Craig

Comment: Thanks. Filed 16312 Publish/Subscribe Issue with support. Both Eric and I are confounded. My code works for him—but not for me. How often have you heard that... :-) cheers Jules

Answer (score 0):

Answer was that there was a copy/paste error with the pub/sub keys.